Overloading Constructor with Generic Class in Java 11
I'm trying to understand two constructors with some initialization like
CardboardContainer<String> n1 = new CardboardContainer<String>("Hello"); // In T constructor

CardboardContainer<String> n2 = new CardboardContainer<String>(3); // In T2 constructor

CardboardContainer<Integer> n22 = new CardboardContainer<Integer>(3); // In T constructor

CardboardContainer<String> n3 = new <Integer>CardboardContainer<String>(3); // In T2 constructor


why does n1 use the first constructor instead of the second constructor?
why does n22 use the second constructor when I change String to Integer? What determines which constructor is chosen in those two commands (n2 vs n22)?
I think n3 will choose the first constructor. Why did it choose the second one?

I have a generic class like this:
class CardboardContainer<T> {
    T myField;

    CardboardContainer(T myField) {
        System.out.println("In T constructor");
        this.myField = myField;
    }

    <T extends Number> CardboardContainer(T myField) {
        System.out.println("In T2 constructor");
//        this.myField = myField;
    }
}


In n1 and n22, the types of the T constructor match the class and parameter types so that works. In the other cases, it doesn't so it has to use the other constructor.

"In n1 and n22, the types of the T constructor match the class and parameter types so that works". I know and I want to know why :(

There should be no problem in understanding the n1 case. <T extends Number> CardboardContainer(T myField) is not applicable to a String at all. The n22 case is the tricky one, as you have to understand why T is more specific that T2 in this case. The simplified answer is that the compiler can infer Number for T2’s type parameter and then, T would be CardboardContainer(Integer) which is more specific than CardboardContainer(Number). Consequently, when you change T2 to <T extends Integer> CardboardContainer(T myField) you’d get a compiler error because of ambiguity.

You've confused yourself to pieces here by shadowing the T. This code is 100% equivalent, as in, the bytecode (class file) is bit for bit identical, and the semantic meaning is also entirely identical:
class CardboardContainer<T> {
    T myField;

    CardboardContainer(T myField) {
        System.out.println("In T constructor");
        this.myField = myField;
    }

    <X extends Number> CardboardContainer(X myField) {
        System.out.println("In X constructor");
//        this.myField = myField;
    }
}

All I've done is rename T to X in that second constructor. That's fine because the 2 Ts are completely unrelated. Like 2 different people who coincidentally are both named 'Jane'. That doesn't magically make them the same person somehow. The <T> in class CardboardContainer<T> is declaring a type variable (whereas the T in the T constructor is using this declared type variable). However, the <X extends Number> here is also declaring a type variable. You've declared 2 variables - one on the type, and one on constructor T2. It is legal to pick the same name for both, but an extremely silly idea that you should absolutely never do; it serves no purpose whatsoever other than confused - and in the context of that method, the T you declared on your T2 constructor 'shadows' the T of the type - anytime you mention T anywhere in that constructor it is assumed to refer to the T you declared on the constructor. But make no mistake, these are two completely, utterly independent type vars that have no relationship whatsoever.
Hence, step 1 to understand this stuff is to stop shadowing T and go with my snippet, which has renamed it X. Now, we can make sense of things:

why does n1 use the first constructor instead of the second constructor?

Because the second constructor can't even be used. The new CardboardContainer<String> part is setting T to String, which means the first constructor 'works' (It requires a T argument; "Hello" is a String, so that works). The second constructor cannot work: The first argument needs to be an X, where the caller gets to pick any X... as long as the caller picks a type that extends Number. No type exists that both [A] extends Number and [B] allows String.

why does n22 use the second constructor when I change String to Integer?

Because in n22, the call 'works' for both constructors - the first constructor works because an Integer is required and 3 is one (Integer is required because you called it with new CardboardConstructor<Integer>, so, T is Inteer) - the second constructor works because the caller must pick some type such that both the argument is that type, and that type extends Number. Integer works as a choice.
Hence, either constructor could be used, and the lang spec then decrees the order in which java picks one. It picks the first. Why? No reason - just, something has to win. It's not random - the spec spells out that the first one wins in such arbitrary cases. There is no stated reason as to why the spec is written like this, nor can I think of one - there probably isn't one. It's just annoying to have to write up in a spec that the compiler must generate an error due to having an ambiguous call here (even though that is more usually how java solves such dilemmas). It simply didn't here; this never comes up because this code is insane and should never be written, ever. Even with the rename. This is too confusing for no benefit.

I think n3 will choose the first constructor. Why did it choose the first one?

You've forced the <X> to be <Integer>. That's what new <A>Foo<B>(); means: Normally for on-method type variables (or in this case, on-constructor - the X in <X extends Number> is an on-constructor type variable declaration), the compiler picks the right type anytime you call it, by just kinda looking at how you call it. But you're free to explicitly choose them. For example:
var x = List.<String>of();

// note, the signature of that method is:

public static <T> List<T> of(T... args) { ... }

If you just write var x = List.of(), the type x would be List<Object> because there's nothing more to go on. But with that explicit <String> in there, the type of x is List<String>. You can explicitly pick generics in constructors too, and thats what the <A> part is about.
You explicitly picked it here which forces the second constructor, because the first constructor has no generics to be explicit about.

I don't understand your sentence "All I've done is rename X to T in that second constructor. That's because they are ..." - do you mean you've renamed T to X? And do you mean they aren't the same?

I’d like to see a link to the place where “the spec spells out that the first one wins in such arbitrary cases”. I’ve never seen such statements and according to which order anyway? Which one is the “first”?

Thank for your amzing answer. For me, you are an expert. The way you analyze problems is captivating, insightful, and clear. I have a mistake because I wrote this question while I was sleepy. The correct question 3 is "I think n3 will choose the first constructor. Why did it choose the second one?". I have updated the question. Sorry for replying later. I need time to understand. Thank you so much! Have a good day!

It’s also wrong that the presence of a type parameter would force the use of the generic constructor. If the OP wrote new <Integer>CardboardContainer<Integer>(3) instead, the compiler picked the non generic constructor, ignoring the type parameter.

@k314159 I edited that part, thanks for noticing!
